# How to solve Multiple definition errors in gcc linux?

Tags: linux, gcc, multiple-definition-error

I am facing below errors when trying to statically link libDuma, Can you tell me how to ask g++ to use malloc from libDuma?

```
sunny@sunny-laptop:~/CodeTest$ g++ ./testDuma.cpp -g  -o testDuma -static -lduma -pthread
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libc.a(malloc.o): In function `free':
(.text+0x4b00): multiple definition of `free'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libduma.a(duma.o):(.text+0x25f0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libc.a(malloc.o): In function `malloc':
(.text+0x4bc0): multiple definition of `malloc'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libduma.a(duma.o):(.text+0x2730): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libc.a(malloc.o): In function `realloc':
(.text+0x5950): multiple definition of `realloc'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libduma.a(duma.o):(.text+0x23d0): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't force a completely static link (don't use the `-static` flag) -- doing so on any modern UNIX system is an extremely bad idea(TM).

Instead, link just the libduma statically. Either of these commands should work:

```
g++ ./testDuma.cpp -g -pthread -o testDuma /path/to/libduma.a
g++ ./testDuma.cpp -g -pthread -o testDuma -Wl,-Bstatic -lduma -Wl,-Bdynamic
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `-nodefaultlibs` flag to not link to libc. Or, remove `-lduma` and link it dynamically after compilation with:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libduma.so ./testDuma
```

Comment: with -nodegaultlibs it is not compiling, I need to statically link libDuma and it is compulsory for me, here are the errors I am getting http://pastebin.com/ydrdqN0J

Comment: @SunnyShah: I'm not sure if it will work correctly, but try `-z muldefs` linker flag. Like: `g++ testDuma.cpp -static -g -o testDuma -lduma -lpthread -Xlinker -z -Xlinker muldefs`

Comment: Thanks for response, one doubt, any idea on how to ask G++ to use the symbols from duma and not from libc?